# Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ

Tags: linq-to-entities

I've tried numerous things to fix what *seems* to be a simple problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Code:

Class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
}

List<MyModel> query = (from ds in dataSource
  group ds by ds.someDate into dsg
  select new MyModel
  {
    date = dsg.Key,
    total = dsg.Sum(ds => ds.Amount)
  }).ToList<MyModel>();
```

Error:

Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'.  LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: @shiv: +1 for cleaning annoying markup.

Comment: my apologies for the markup.  this is my first question to the site, and new lines and spaces weren't showing before adding the markup...

Comment: It seems that what I thought was the problem is not the problem.  The code above actually works and it was another column in my select that was causing this issue.  Where is the UNDO button for posting stupid questions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `MyModel.date` property from `object` to `DateTime`.

Alternatively, change your code to

```
List<DateTime> dates = dataSource.Select(ds => ds.someDate)
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: It is already a DateTime property. There are other properties being returned in the query that I didn't show (to simplify the code)...so I need the group by clause.

Comment: I added the basic class definition and aggregate property.

Comment: @user: The class definition you added has no relation to the LINQ query whatsoever.  If you're making changes to it to protect your code, that's fine.  But it should still be _working_ code.

Comment: Added definition for MyModel.

Comment: Changed again...sorry for the confusion.  It is surprisingly difficult to recreate code to try to simplify it.